# Jquery UI dialog opens twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've got a problem with the UI Dialog.

After closing the dialog and reopening it, the dialog appears twice. One dialog with the old form data (which I dont want) and a new empty dialog.

I am closing the dialog after form submit in the following way:

```
$('.ui-dialog-titlebar-close').click();
```

I have also tried closing it this way:

```
$(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close');
```

Have anyone experienced similar behaviour?

Comment: try destroy() method on it , if possible set up a fiddle in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While closing make sure that the dialog self-destructs..

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
  .
  .
  .
  close: function(){
     $(this).dialog("destroy");// I also use .remove() but its redundant
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Robin. I just noticed that even if the second dialog disappeard when using your tip it does two requests the next time I am posting my form.. Got any solution to this?

Comment: @f01: Making "two requests" to? Sorry I still don't get the picture. Probably a fiddle? Or you could even ask a separate question altogether.

Answer (score 0):

try `.dialog( "destroy" )` method.  [Dialog.destroy](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-destroy)

```
$(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('destroy');
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put

```
          event.preventDefault():
```

which can stop the behaviour like this